# How do I tune my SQL update to improve performance?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization

I have a windows service developed in .net / c#.

It frequently updates a table with location data stored in SQL server. The update SQL query is etremely slow, somwehere between 0.5-1.5 sec. In this table there are not more than 1500 records.

Would you be so kind to help me to find what I miss? There should be sg with this update, I have others that work perfectly and fast.

Thanks a lot!

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [LastPosition] (
[lastposition_id] INTEGER  IDENTITY NOT NULL,
[unit_id] INTEGER  NOT NULL,
[date_time] DATETIME  NOT NULL,
[valid] TINYINT  NOT NULL,
[lat] REAL NOT NULL,
[lon] REAL NOT NULL,
[angle] SMALLINT NOT NULL,
[speed] SMALLINT NOT NULL,
[digit] TINYINT NOT NULL,
[altitude] SMALLINT NULL,
[sat] TINYINT NULL,
[extrainfo] NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
[geoinfo] TINYINT NULL,
CONSTRAINT LastPositionPrimaryKey PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED(lastposition_id));
```

Query:

```
exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE [LastPosition] 
 SET [LastPosition].[Unit_id]=@up_Unit_id, 
[LastPosition].[Date_Time]=@up_Date_Time, 
[LastPosition].[Valid]=@up_Valid, 
[LastPosition].[Lat]=@up_Lat, 
[LastPosition].[Lon]=@up_Lon, 
[LastPosition].[Angle]=@up_Angle, 
[LastPosition].[Speed]=@up_Speed, 
[LastPosition].[Digit]=@up_Digit, 
[LastPosition].[Altitude]=@up_Altitude, 
[LastPosition].[Sat]=@up_Sat, 
[LastPosition].[ExtraInfo]=@up_ExtraInfo, 
[LastPosition].[GeoInfo]=@up_GeoInfo
 WHERE [LastPosition].[LastPosition_id] = @0',N'@up_Unit_id int,@up_Date_Time datetime,@up_Valid int,@up_Lat float,@up_Lon float,@up_Angle int,@up_Speed int,@up_Digit int,@up_Altitude int,@up_Sat int,@up_ExtraInfo nvarchar(13),@up_GeoInfo int,@0 int',@up_Unit_id=1164,@up_Date_Time='2022-09-19 10:21:33.457',@up_Valid=1,@up_Lat=49,612609999999997,@up_Lon=15,922759999999999,@up_Angle=127,@up_Speed=0,@up_Digit=255,@up_Altitude=138,@up_Sat=19,@up_ExtraInfo=N'Kkt löueléket',@up_GeoInfo=27,@0=1111
```

UPDATE:
There are no any views on this table. There are no any triggers. I don't have connection issues.

Query plan:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try to execute the query and display it's actual execution plan (and associated timings) in SQL Server Management Studio ? It should give you a pretty good view of what is taking that much time.

Comment: Alternatively, do you have triggers and/or additional indexes set up on your table, it might not be the query itself being slow, but index updates or triggers being executed.

Comment: Test your query in ssms and check if any connection issue exists!

Comment: We need at a minimum the query plan, which you can share via https://pastetheplan.com. Are there any other indexes? The fact the primary key is non-clustered is very concerning

Comment: "It frequently updates a table" does it man concurrently also? Either way Sql Server comes with a Profiler tool that should give you hints what is taken the time here. "Remote" diagnosing is hard without data.

Comment: In addition to @Irwene question, do you have any indexed views, using LastPosition table?

Comment: @Charlieface Maybe another website, pastetheplan.com seems down.

Comment: Thanks to all, I have updated with the post with info you asked.

Comment: Your table's primary key matches the `WHERE` in your UPDATE statement: that is good. But you have declared it `NONCLUSTERED`. If you have a good reason for that, please [edit] your question to explain. Otherwise, try removing `NONCLUSTERED` from the declaration.  Processing single rows is quicker when they're accessed via the clustered index behind the pk. [Read this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7741/when-should-a-primary-key-be-declared-non-clustered).

Comment: The query plan looks OK, although the fact the primary key is non-clustered is likely to cause deadlocks. Are there any other queries running concurrently?

Comment: I updated it to clustered now, but no effect on speed. There are only select queries on this table, no concurrent updates.

Comment: Here is the plan after updating it to clustered: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rk2HHAS-j

Comment: Could you check the usage of your tempdb ? If it's full, it might be one of the reasons you have slow queries.

Comment: According to tempdb properties, its size is 1064 MB, 1053.24 space available

Comment: Have you checked for short-term blocking, where select queries block updates? Do you have indexes to support efficient select queries (avoiding scans that block updates) .

Comment: What happens to the performance if you put `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` right at the end of your query (after the WHERE clause)?

Comment: Thanks for all your advice, I will come back later today, all suggestions helped me to go to the right direction, it seems I have a great improvement on the right way. I will write the details.

Comment: I'd be guessing the problem is not in the query but in the infrastructure around it, because it looks good from the info you provided. Do you cache the connections in the service or create new ones on the fly? Even without indexes, it should not take this long time to update a single row out of 1500, unless you run the server on a raspberry pi or a samsung fridge

Comment: You need to give the **actual** execution plan. Not estimated. The actual execution plan XML contains per operator timings, info about numbers of pages reads, and wait stats

Comment: @Tom, I see a plan with only a clustered index update operator when I run the query against the table with only the clustered primary key. This is the most optimal plan and you should see same. I find it odd the plan in the PasteThePlan link has additional operators and no SQL text so I'm guessing it's different than the one in your question. That said, the exceeding long duration for such a small table suggest blocking, undersized server, or infrastructure issue.

Comment: I had a problem like that. In this case I prefered to delete and insert the record instead of update the record. All problems were solved. Maybe it works for you. Try it and let me know the result. And define the primary key as clustered.

Comment: Do you know for sure that it is definitely the UPDATE statement that is taking that amount of time?   That is, does it take that long when you run the UPDATE directly via SQL management studio?  In reality, if you do have a SQL Server that is taking over a second to update a single, indexed record in a table of only 1500 records, you need to take a serious look at the underlying server OS and infrastructure.  As in, you're probably need to look at using SQL Profiler and Windows Performance Monitor (assuming it's running on Windows) to identify any bottlenecks

Comment: Also, is there any difference in the execution time and/or the corresponding execution plan if you just directly run an UPDATE statement without using sp_executesql?

Answer (score 2):

Considering there are no views, triggers, or connection issues, there are several potential reasons

1.add an index on LastPosition_id column you are filtering on this column in the WHERE  an index should significantly improve performance (JUST IN CASE)

2.avoid updating all columns in one query break it into multiple querie updating fewer columns and  This reduces locking/blocking

2.if frequently need to update many rows consider using BULK update instead of row-by-row updates this minimizes logging overhead this is an exapmple

```
CREATE TABLE #LastPositionUpdates  
(
   LastPosition_id INT,
   Unit_id INT,
   Date_Time DATETIME,
   Valid BIT,
   Lat FLOAT,
   Lon FLOAT,
   -- other columns to update
)

-- Insert updates into staging table in c#
INSERT INTO #LastPositionUpdates 
VALUES
   (1111, 1164, '2022-09-19 10:21:33.457', 1, 49.612609999999997, 15.922759999999999),
   (2222, 1165, '2022-09-19 10:22:11.123', 0, 49.61265, 15.92280),
   -- insert other rows to update

-- Join staging table to target and update
UPDATE lp
SET 
   lp.Unit_id = lu.Unit_id,
   lp.Date_Time = lu.Date_Time,
   lp.Valid = lu.Valid,
   lp.Lat = lu.Lat, 
   lp.Lon = lu.Lon
   -- set other columns
FROM LastPosition lp
JOIN #LastPositionUpdates lu
  ON lp.LastPosition_id = lu.LastPosition_id

-- Drop temporary table
DROP TABLE #LastPositionUpdates
```

3. Make sure your database statistics are up-to-date, so the query optimizer can create optimal query plans. Run UPDATE STATISTICS on the table and heck for blocking or deadlocks using SQL Server Profiler